# Не показывать карточку товара если нет?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть интернет-магазин у некоторых товаров отсутствуют карточки товара(нет описании, нет дополнительных фотографии, рекомендуемые товары). Как можно реализовать функционал, в каталоге и в корзине чтобы ссылка на карточку товара была не активно? Только у некоторых товаров. Заранее спасибо.

Насколько я знаю код отвечающий на переход на карточку товара это

```
the_permalink();
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все не так просто. страница магазина формируется в `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php`, вывод отдельного товара в `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php`. Но и там нет формирования ссылки, которое производится во внутренних функциях `woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open()` и `woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close()`.

Эти функции формирования ссылки висят на хуках `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item` и `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item`.

Для подключения своих функций формирования ссылки надо сначала отменить хуки `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item` и `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item`, и подключить свои.

Код в functions.php выглядит так:

```
function my_woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open() {
    global $product;
    if ($product->sku) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link">';
    }
}

function my_woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close() {
    global $product;
    if ($product->sku) {
        echo '</a>';
    }
}

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'my_woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'my_woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close', 5 );
```

В приведенном **рабочем примере** проверяется, имеет ли товар sku, и если имеет - то выполняется стандартный код формирования ссылки, скопированный из функций `woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open()` и `woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close()`. (Он очень простой - всего одна строка).

Вам следует вместо проверки sku товара вставить свое условие, при котором надо формировать ссылку.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: Можете подсказать откуда можно получить данные глобальной переменной $product, я пробовал через var_dump, выходит null. Спасибо за код

Comment: чтобы получить ее значение, нужно внутри функции, где вывод, объявить ее global $product;  (как в ответе)